# Install my own copy of Windows 7 Retail on a Lenovo PC with BIOS-based license

Tags: windows-7, bios, license, windows-activation, lenovo-desktop-computer

I have acquired a Lenovo PC. Whatever OS was installed is long gone, the hard drive is totally wiped.

I plan to install my own (legitimate) copy of Windows 7 x64 Retail.

The BIOS *seems* to have some kind of license built into it. In BIOS Setup I see the following read-only entry:

**License Status: NOK**

Google search returns a few results relating to Windows 8 activation, but nothing on NOK specifically.

Anyway I'm just wondering if the license built into the BIOS, if that's what it is, will interfere with the installation and most importantly *activation* of my genuine retail edition of Windows 7?

**EDIT:** This is a *Lenovo M73 Tower* PC. From what I see on Lenovo's website it generally ships with Windows 8 and allows downgrade rights to Windows 7.

**EDIT 2:** I know I can obtain recovery disks from Lenovo, but I'd prefer to install my own retail Windows 7 as it's the Ultimate edition.

Comment: You need to tell us what operating system it came with.  Without that information we cannot answer this question.

Comment: @Ramhound It's a M73 which means, I'm pretty sure, it usually ships with Windows 8 with downgrade rights to Windows 7. Question has been edited.

Comment: Why are you not sure; Anyways if it did come with Windows 8; the key is indeed inbedded; which is meanongless if you are installing Windows 7

Comment: I wonder if NOK is a Lenovo term as I've seen it on their forums...

Comment: Windows 7 license keys were never stored in the bios that's only windows 8, which means? The user just inputs the license key like normal

Comment: @Ramhound You're right, installed and activated my Win7 just now and all is good. If you write up a quick answer I'll mark is as correct :-)